# Registering S3method with "<-" in NAMESPACE

Tags: r, namespaces

I have a function `"time.foo<-"`  in a package with R code like this:

```
"time.foo<-" <- function(x,value){ STUFF }
```

The function works as intended. But I'm confused about how to document `time.foo<-` properly and add it to the NAMESPACE.

In NAMESPACE I add it to the export list as:

```
export("time.foo<-")
```

That is correct I believe. But I also have to register it as an S3method in NAMESPACE. Correct? What does that syntax look like? This is not right:

```
S3method("time","foo","<-")
```

Nor is this:

```
S3method("time<-","foo")
```

I will also need to create the  `Rd` file for this function. And the `usage` section would need to read something like this I think:

```
\usage{
  \method{time}{foo}(x) <- value
}
```

Is that correct?

I am not using `roxygen2` which I suppose I should be. But for now I'd just like to know how to hardcode this in NAMESPACE. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define a generic assignment for your function (The `stats` pacakge only defines a generic `time()`, not `time<-()`) in addition to the actual function implementation for your class

```
`time<-` <- function (x, ...) {
  UseMethod("time<-", x)
}
`time<-.foo` <- function(x, value) { 
  STUFF
}
```

And then you would have these in your NAMESPACE

```
export("time<-")
S3method("time<-",foo)
```

The usage doesn't have to be marked up. Just show something like

```
\usage{
time(foo) <- value
}
```

Often you would also have a `time.foo()` function. Those functions are commonly documented on the same help page. See `class<-` for example. Or check out a page like `?plot.formula` to see that you generally don't encourage people to call the specific `.foo` methods directly. Those should be found through dispatch.

Even if you don't want to use roxygen for your project, it probably wouldn't hurt if you get suck to set up a text roxygen project that you can test simple stuff like this to see what it outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still running into problems. E.g., `Warning: S3 method ‘time<-.foo’ was declared in NAMESPACE but not found` Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you define that function in your package code? It’s hard to say what’s going on without some thing to test with.

Comment: It is tricky I know. I'll mess about with it some. Thanks for the start and the spending the time.

Comment: Got it. The assignment was in the wrong place in my code. My function had to be set as: `time<-.foo` <- function(x, value) {  STUFF }. Passing --as-cran now. Phew. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry. Missed that.

Comment: It's confusing syntax.